# Замена предыдущего значения EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть числовой EditText максимальная длина 2 символа, по умолчанию значение 00. С помощью TextWatcher получаеться отслеживать ввод символов, но если достигнута максимальная длина ничего не происходит. Как можно заменять старое значение новым?

Comment: Не очень понятно, какая у вас проблема. Вы хотите, чтобы последующие нажатия на кнопки (третье и тд) забивали уже введенные два числа, например при последовательном нажатии на кнопки 1 2 3 4 в поле ввода должно остаться 34 ?

Comment: Да, именно так. Подобное реализовано в стандартном таймере

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(et.getText().length()==2)
                    et.setSelection(0,2);
                return false;
            }
});
```

Когда будут введены две цифры, они сразу выделяются и если продолжить ввод, они будут заменяться на новые.
Я правильно понял, вам это надо?

Comment: Не совсем. У меня данный код отрабатывает только по нажатию кнопки ОК. Ввел новые значения нажал ок клавиатура скрылась, текст выделился, но если повторно нажать на редактирование то снимается выделение

Comment: @Doom, тоесть вам теперь нужно при клике на EditText выделять текст в нем? Как в Chrome, в адресной строке?

Comment: Да. Не подскажите есть ли возможность отключить визуализацию выделения?

Comment: @Doom, да. Сделайте эту визуализацию прозрачной, добавив в тэг EditText `android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    setSelection(this.length());
}

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() > 0) {
            removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.toString());

            setText(sb.deleteCharAt(0));
            addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```